# several random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables over a sample space $S$. My professor states that the joint distribution function is defined as $F(x,y) = P(X \leq x,Y \leq y)$, but I don't see what $P(X \leq x,Y \leq y)$ actually means. Indeed, how is $P(X=a,Y=b)$ defined, given the variables $X,Y$. Is there a natural way to do this?

Comment: It is the probability that $X\le x$ **and** $Y\le y$. Geometrically, it is the probability that $(X,Y)$ lies "below and to the left of" point $(x,y)$. As such, it is the natural generalization to two random variables of the cumulative distribution function, which is $\Pr(X\le x)$. On your second question, the probability that $X=a$ **and** $Y=b$ is often not interesting, since in the continuous case it is always $0$.